# Como fazer dois inner Join em uma tabela?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio

```
CREATE TABLE FUNCAO
(
ID_FUNCAO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
NOME_FUNCAO VARCHAR(100),
SALARIO VARCHAR(100),
DATA VARCHAR(100),
CONSTRAINT PK_FUNCAO PRIMARY KEY (ID_FUNCAO)
)
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTAMENTO
(
ID_DEPARTAMENTO INT IDENTITY(1,1),
NOME_DEP VARCHAR(100),
ID_FUNCAO INT,
CONSTRAINT PK_DEP PRIMARY KEY (ID_DEPARTAMENTO),
CONSTRAINT PK_DEP_FUNCAO FOREIGN KEY (ID_FUNCAO)
REFERENCES FUNCAO (ID_FUNCAO)
)
```

No Programa VS a comboBox Função e Salário
Os dados vêm atraves da tabela função(fiz inner join)

Eu pretendo que na data gridview apareça as duas tabelas?
só aparece uma.
**Como fazer dois inner join num select?**

Estou a usar esse select

```
string sql4A = "SELECT DP.ID_DEPARTAMENTO, DP.NOME_DEP, FUNCAO.NOME_FUNCAO, FUNCAO.ID_FUNCAO FROM DEPARTAMENTO AS DP INNER JOIN FUNCAO ON DP.ID_FUNCAO = FUNCAO.ID_FUNCAO";
```

Comment: *"na data gridview apareça as duas tabelas? só aparece uma"* isso não está claro, coloque o código com mais detalhes. Você pregunta como fazer dois joins mas só tem duas tabelas, apenas um join já liga as duas, o que exatamente quer fazer que precisar fazer outro join?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Com as tabelas que você colocou na pergunta fazemos apenas um inner join.
Para exibir o conteúdo das duas tabelas você deve colocar os campos que deseja exibir logo após o comando select.
Segue exemplo abaixo:

```sql
select fc.ID_FUNCAO, fc.NOME_FUNCAO, fc.SALARIO, fc.DATA, dp.ID_DEPARTAMENTO, dp.NOME_DEP  
from funcao fc 
inner join departamento dp 
on dp.id_funcao = fc.id_funcao
```

Porém caso queira fazer mais um inner join, você deve colocar logo após o final da query citada acima o inner join a mais.
Vou deixar como se fosse uma fórmula

```sql
Select * 
from table1 tb1
inner join table2 tb2 
on tb2.id_tb1 = tb1.id
inner join table3 tb3
on tb3.id_tb2 = tb3.id
(...)
```